# My dog ate my unicoins

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins, april-fools

I had a lot of unicoins, but i left them unattended and my dog ate most of them. 
I wonder if SE would accept a dog full of unicoins as a payment.

Comment: Buy more with bacon?

Comment: [Freddy star ate MY unicorns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddie_Starr#.22Freddie_Starr_ate_my_hamster.22)? What's SO's policy on THAT?!

Comment: the question will be deleted (since it is off-topic), and some great replies will be lost. I think it doesn't bother anyone and i will cry!  Thanks for the fun guys!

Answer (score 14):

The only thing you can do is to use unicorns against your dog.

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Welp, I'm convinced :)

Comment: Well, if everything else fails, just ask the unicorn to start whining. I'm pretty sure that the dog will start mining instead of you.

Answer (score 10):

Wait at the other end of your dog. At some point the Unicoins will pass as, one could only hope, Dogecoins.

Answer (score 6):

I have heard that if you change your avatar to your personal unicorn your unicoins will be protected!

Go to http://unicornify.appspot.com/use-it fast and change your avatar to be safe!

It works for me so it should work for you to!

***EDIT:***
I just found out how the unicorn protects the unicoins, it used its custom laser eyes to kill the thiefs. It looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Unicornify tends to run over quota pretty quick on April 1st (mainly because of [this](http://www.cravingtech.com/how-to-remove-the-unicorn-avatar-in-mystique-wordpress-theme.html)), so hurry...

Answer (score 5):

SE will not accept unicoins that have been ingested by your dog because your dog has already accepted the unicoins as payment.

Answer (score 3):

such unicoin, much taste. Wow!

Answer (score 2):

That's simple feed your unicorns with your dog and it will multiple by the factor of unicoin's he ate.